# Using flutter_unity_widget and create a plugin with my unity project

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, android-unity-plugin

I would like to use flutter_unity_widget in order to embed my unity project and use it as a plugin in apps.

I followed this link:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget

but it isn't compiled as:

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_unity_widget-0.1.6+8\android\build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_unity_widget'.
> Project with path ':unity-classes' could not be found in project ':flutter_unity_widget'.
```

while line 39 in flutter_unity_widget android build.gradle is the dependency:

```
implementation project(':unity-classes')
```

[follow this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOlgq.png)

Steps:

1. I added the unity project in the root folder

2. I opened it in Unity, set the player settings and exported it to Android.
3. pubspec.yaml:
   flutter_unity_widget: ^0.1.6+5
4. root android / settings.gradle:

   ```
   include ":UnityExport"
   project(":UnityExport").projectDir = file("./UnityExport")
   ```
5. root android / UnityExport/build.gradle:

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation project(':unity-classes')
   }
   ```
6. file -> project structures -> modules: added unity-classes.jar as a module

I'm trying to run the plugin but get the above error.

**Any idea what is wrong?**

Comment: Got the same issue, Do you have any idea to solve it ???

Comment: No but we gave up using unity so I'm sorry I can't assist.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add 2 lines at the bottom of settings.gradle file (android/settings.gradle). The settings.gradle file is in main android project, not in flutter_unity_widget project.

```
include ":unity-classes"

project(":unity-classes").projectDir = file("./unity-classes")
```